# Error: unbound method Dragon( ) must be called with Enemy instance as first argument (got Player instance instead)

Tags: python, methods, instance, init

```
class Character: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.health = 1
        self.health_max = 1

class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self):
        Character.__init__(self)
        self.state = 'normal'
        self.health = 10
        self.health_max = 10

class Monster(Character):
    def Dragon(self):
        self.name = "Dragon"
        self.health = 20

    def Goblin(self):
        name = "Goblin"
        health = 5

p = Player()
p.name = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print p.name
print p.state
print p.health
print p.health_max

m = Monster()
enemy = m.Dragon
print enemy.name
print enemy.health
```

Sorry, I've made this a little simpler to explain what I'm having difficulty with. I'm having a little bit of trouble with the basics of OOP, and I'm running into an issue with this snippet of code. I'm trying to create a "Dragon" here but I'm running into the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "test2.py", line 32, in 
>           print enemy.name
>       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see `enemy` defined anywhere. Is there some typo in the question, or should `myenemy` be `enemy`?

Comment: Good catch, I've changed it to enemy, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an instance of a class first before you call any functions from it:

```
myenemy = Enemy()
myenemy.Dragon()
```

In your code, it looks like you created `self.enemy`, but later you call `self.enemy = Enemy.Dragon(self)`. Instead of this last line, put `self.enemy = self.enemy.Dragon(self)`.

It seems to be a recurring issue in the rest of your code as well. `Commands = {'explore': Player.explore}` should probably be `Commands = {'explore': p.explore}` (after you have created the instance `p`).

---

Since your updated code, I think you're getting functions and classes mixed up. `Dragon` is a function, and when you do `enemy = m.Dragon`, you are simply copying the function onto enemy. And thus when you do `enemy.name`, thinking it's a class, an error is raised, because `enemy` is now a function, not an instance.

You will have to create separate classes for different monsters:

```
class Dragon:
    self.name = "Dragon"
    self.health = 20

class Goblin:
    name = "Goblin"
    health = 5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've changed the format of my question a little bit to explain better what I'm having trouble with. Would appreciate if you took the chance to look at the edited question. THanks.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Need to brush up on my understanding of functions and classes.